# What is the Exceedingly Rare Special item?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

So a [recent update](http://blog.counter-strike.net/armsdeal/) turned CS:GO into a microtransaction model similar to DotA2 and TF2.

As such, one of the weapon crates lists:

```
                              eSports 2013 Case

                            Base Grade Weapon Case
                                Case Series #2

This case contains one of the following:
    - M4A4 | Faded Zebra
    - MAG-7 | Memento
    - FAMAS | Doomkitty
    - Galil AR | Orange DDPAT
    - Sawed-Off | Orange DDPAT
    - P250 | Splash
    - AK-47 | Red Laminate
    - AWP | BOOM
    - P90 | Death by Kitty
      or an Exceedingly Rare Special Item
```

So what is this Exceedingly Rare Special Item? Is it like TF2, where hats would be uncrated with the Unusual particle effect, and do weapons get that too? Or is it something else entirely?

Comment: There's nothing unusual about that gun: http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/CS%3AGO%20Weapon%20Case Ingame shows the rarity color. That's why I suggested that the '★' symbol is for the 'exceedingly rare special items'

Comment: Oh, I thought the purple color represented the quality, hence the "unusual" items

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The '*Exceedingly Rare Special Items*' are the different knife models. Knives unboxed can come in either a normal version or also have the chance of coming with StatTrak.

From [Steam News](http://store.steampowered.com/news/11265/):

> Weapon Cases have a chance to contain new **knives** and StatTrak weapons,
> which track all player kills with that weapon.

The different knives that can be unboxed are:

- Bayonet
- M9 Bayonet
- Gut Knife
- Flip Knife
- Karambit
- Huntsman Knife
- Butterfly Knife
- Falchion Knife

The `★` symbol is the CS:GO version of `Unusual`.
Knives unboxed will have the following name:

> ★ KNIFE_TYPE | PATTERN

So if you unboxed a Flip Knife Night, you would see:

> ★ FLIP KNIFE | NIGHT

Comment: Then it looks to just be the different knife models.

Comment: Note that in certain cases, yellow (gold) items can also be Gloves instead of Knives

Answer (score 3):

Last night I unboxed an Exceedingly Rare Special Item. It was a `★ Gut Knife | Blue Steel`. And I'm loving it.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

The *Exceedingly Rare Special Item* is YELLOW according to the crate description.

Purple is *Classified*.

*Strange* aka *StatTrak* are Orange versions of weapons.

And on top of that there are different finishes, [NEW being the best](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=169698044).